# How to show a function is differentiable n times.

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(x)$ is differentiable $n$ times, how to show $f(x^k)$ is also differentiable $n$ times. It is intuitively true, but chain rule does not work out very well, any advice?

Comment: [Faa di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) is useful. It basically says that the $n$th derivative of $f\circ g$ is a combination of the lower derivatives. So if all of the lower derivatives of $f$ and $g$ exist, $f\circ g$ is $n$ times differentiable.

Comment: But we are not allowed to use theorems we didn't prove in class. So I don't think I can use this one... Is there any other ways to prove existence?

Comment: I'm not saying use the formula but gain some insight from it. Try proving that the $m$th derivative of $f\circ g$ only contains derivatives of each of at most order $m$. (Induction might be useful here.) Since $f$ is $n$ times differentiable and $x^k$ is infinitely differentiable, $f(x^k)$ is $n$ times differentiable.

Comment: I will try. Thanks

Comment: By "$f(x)$ is differentiable $n$ times," do you mean that $f$ is $n$-times differentiable at $x$, or that $f$ is $n$-times differentiable everywhere?

Comment: Sorry, only at $x$. If it were everywhere, I am done..

Comment: Then I don't think it's true. Take $f(x) = |x-1|$. Then $f'(-1)=-1$, but $f'((-1)^2)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: You are right...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try to prove it by induction on $n$ ...

NB: you can replace $f(x^k)$ by $f \circ g$ with $g$ differentiable $n$ times